# How to pull a dependency with specific setting in a conanfile.py?

Tags: conan

I am creating a recipe for my project.  The project has a dependency on a package, for example "pcapplusplus/18.08".  Easy enough, I do this with:

```
class MyProject(ConanFile):
    name = "myproject"
    version = "0.1"
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"

    # ...simplified...

    requires = "pcapplusplus/18.08"

    # ... configure, build etc
```

Except the pcapplusplus dependency has to be pulled with the setting `compiler.version=15`.  Akin to this syntax in a profile:

```
[settings]
pcapplusplus:compiler.version=15
```

Or from `conan install`:

```
conan install . -s pcapplusplus:compiler.version=15
```

How is this done in a `conanfile.py`?

Answer (score 0):

The `[settings]` you are describing is not a `conanfile.txt`. It is a profile file that must be used as:

```
$ conan install <path-to-conanfile> --profile=<path-to-profile>
```

The profile files can be used both for `conanfile.txt` and `conanfile.py` files.

Comment: Shoot you are right my example was bad.  I will edit the question for future readers.  But you see what I mean, the question still stands unanswered, there's a way with conan install to "tweak" the settings for a articular dependency and how would you get the same effect from a conanfile.py?

Comment: Yes, this is not possible to do from conanfiles, it can only be done in profiles/command line. This was not done because it introduces another sets of problems, like conflicting configurations of dependencies in graphs with diamond structures, similar to what already happens with versions and options conflicts (which is a challenging and confusing thing, better not replicate the same issue with settings), or confusing misunderstandings of the defaults and precedence.